# Binding Infragistics UltraChart (lineplot) to DataView

Tags: c#, data-binding, infragistics, dataview

I'm trying to bind a DataView to NumericTimeSeries through its NumericTimeSeriesDataAppearance instance, but the series end up having zero points. I'm testing using the following code:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));
table.Columns.Add("value", typeof(double));

DataView view = new DataView(table);
view.AllowDelete = true;
view.AllowNew = true;
view.AllowEdit = true;

NumericTimeSeries series = new NumericTimeSeries();
series.Data.TimeValueColumn = "date";
series.Data.ValueColumn = "value";
series.Data.DataSource = view;
series.DataBind();

// Update series when data is changed
view.ListChanged += (sender, args) => series.DataBind();
table.RowChanged += (sender, args) => series.DataBind();
table.TableNewRow += (sender, args) => series.DataBind();
table.RowDeleted += (sender, args) => series.DataBind();

table.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now, 42.0);

System.Console.WriteLine("Number of datapoints in view is {0}", view.Count);            
System.Console.WriteLine("Number of datapoints in series is {0}", series.Points.Count);
```

This outputs 1 datapoint for the view, but 0 for the series. Binding directly to the DataTable works fine, but isn't sufficient for my problem (I'm using a DataView to sort a DataTable on date).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a trigger for events DataTable.RowChanged, TableNewRow and RowDeleted updating the NumericTimeSeries:

```
    public void BindSortedViewToSeries(DataTable unsortedTable, DataView sortedView, NumericTimeSeries series)
    {
        unsortedTable.RowChanged += (sender, args) => MirrorDataView(sortedView, series);
        unsortedTable.TableNewRow += (sender, args) => MirrorDataView(sortedView, series);
        unsortedTable.RowDeleted += (sender, args) => MirrorDataView(sortedView, series);
        MirrorDataView(view, series);
    }

    private static void MirrorDataView(DataView view, NumericTimeSeries series)
    {
        series.Data.DataSource = view.ToTable();
        series.DataBind();
    }
```